# Inserting new record or updating record by updating a value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Cart table. Users can add products to Cart. I m using php to add or insert records.

Cart Table consists of :

```
CartID, CartProductID, CartQty, CartPrice, CartUserID
```

Now a user shud not be able to add same product on cart table again but instead it should update an value of CartQty if product exist. What can be the sql for such an update?

I can create multiple button & using hide & show javascript if product already exist on cart or if not.

Example of an Data:

```
CartID, CartProductID, CartQty, CartPrice,CartUserID

1, 10, 1, 100, 4

2, 11, 2, 150, 4
```

Now if a UserID with 4 wants to Add ProductID 10 into cart again then CartQty value should add up based on qty input field.

If qty input field is 3 then 1st record should update as:

`1, 10, 4, 100, 4`

Comment: share your code from where you are adding products in cart

Comment: This doesn't make sense. You wouldn't normally store the user id and the contents of the cart in the same table.

Answer (score 1):

An example of a valid schema might be somewhat as follows:

```
cart
 cart_id *
 user_id
 expiry_date

cart_detail
 cart_id *
 product_id *
 quantity

product
 product_id *
 date *
 price

* = (component of) PRIMARY KEY
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it, in SQL, Suppose @CartProductID = 10 and @CartQty =1

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Table1 WHERE CartProductID=@CartProductID)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Table1 (CartID, CartProductID, CartQty, CartPrice,CartUserID)
    VALUES (1, 10, 1, 100, 4)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    UPDATE Table1 SET CartQty=CartQty+@CartQty WHERE CartProductID=@CartProductID
END
```

Comment: Well, it's not what I'd do.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can `INSERT` with a `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause, provided you created the correct `UNIQUE` clause, which, according to me, should be `CartID, CartProductID, CartUserID`.

See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/insert-on-duplicate-key-update/ for further information about `ON DUPLICATE KEY`